# Can my friend (mac user) boot the QEMU virtual machines that I created in Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am using Ubuntu, but my friend is on Mac. Can I create a VM in QEMU in ubuntu and them "give" him my virtual machine file so that he can boot the system?

Comment: I know in Virtual box I can make a VM on my Windows PC and  move it to my Ubuntu machine and launch it and it works and the same in reverse making it on Ubuntu and moving it to Windows.. so I guess it would be possible making one in Ubuntu and copying it to a Mac. ... don't know about VMware tho .. it may work differently

Comment: Yes as long as they have access to the virtual drive. You can duplicate the drive if needed or again if needed convert to raw or qcow image